# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax with print json.dumps(result)

Tags: python

Ok so I'm new to python. I have a script that I am writing to better understand the concepts in python. I am trying to pass back a dictionary as json at the terminus of the script but it is giving me an invalid syntax error. The odd thing is that the place it is saying I have an error is a direct copy from a simpler version that works.

So here is the script:

```
import sys, json, argparse

# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='pace data')
    parser.add_argument('--funct', '-m', required=False, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--id', '-i', required=False, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--email', '-p', required=False, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--firstName', '-f', required=False, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--lastName', '-l', required=False, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--password', '-w', required=False, default='')
    result = {}
    result['PHPEmail'] = args.email
    result['PHPID'] = args.id
    result['PHPfirstName'] = args.firstName
    result['PHPlastName'] = args.lastName
    result['PHPpassword'] = args.password
    result['status'] = 'good'


# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)
```

I execute with this command line call:

```
$ python send_php4.py --id "45333323345" --email "foo@gmail.com" --firstName "firstfoo" --lastName "lastfoo" --password "00P4FOO@00"
```

Here is the error I get:

```
  File "send_php4.py", line 29
    print json.dumps(result)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You forget the `except`, you cannot have a try without a closing except

Comment: Probably that line is just under your `try` block. Python does not support `try` blocks without a matching `except` block.

Comment: I had the same error, but it was because I was using a python 3.x interpreter and print without parenthesis is python 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close the try block. Use for example:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    print "Something wrong"
else:
    print json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it. now it only prints error. Happen to spot any other blunders?